Can not start postgres on MacOS
I want to run postgres on my MacOS
I have the following situation:
brew services start  postgresql@15
==> Successfully started `postgresql@15` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@15)
aamoskalenko@AAMOSKALENKO 44_feast_ui_backend % brew services list                
Name          Status     User         File
mysql         none                    
mysql@8.0     none                    
postgresql@15 error  256 aamoskalenko ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@15.plist

I was trying
psql
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  database "aamoskalenko" does not exist



#also I see 
lsof -i:5432
COMMAND    PID         USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
postgres 63404 aamoskalenko    7u  IPv6 0x664140fda6b83786      0t0  TCP localhost:postgresql (LISTEN)
postgres 63404 aamoskalenko    8u  IPv4 0x535a9a2befafea7b      0t0  TCP localhost:postgresql (LISTEN)


The server has started, the issue  is you cannot connect.  That is because you just doing just psql. You need to spend some time reading psql. In meantime psql by itself will assume your OS user name as the Postgres user name and as the database name you are connecting to.  aamoskalenko is not a Postgres database in your cluster so it can't connect. You need to use a database name that does exist, that would be postgres.
